# TypeError when plotting heatmap with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn

I have the following dataset in a pandas DataFrame, which I've tidied and saved into `"filename1.csv"`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename1.csv")
print(df)

    samples a       b       c       percent_a   percent_c   ratio_a:b   ratio_c:b
0   sample1 185852  6509042 253303  0.028553    0.038916    35.022717   25.696664
1   sample2 218178  6456571 273448  0.033792    0.042352    29.593135   23.611696
2   sample3 251492  6353453 343252  0.039584    0.054026    25.263042   18.509588
3   sample4 232299  6431376 284522  0.036120    0.044240    27.685767   22.604143
..............................
```

I would like to plot this DataFrame as a heatmap using seaborn. At first, it would be interesting to see the samples (one sample per row) against two columns, `percent_a` and `percent_c`:

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# drop unnecessary columns
df = df.drop(["a", "b", "c", "ratio_a:b", "ratio_c:b"], axis = 1)
sns.heatmap(df)
plt.show()
```

However, this throws an error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs 
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I originally thought this meant that there were `NaN` values in this DataFrame. However, it appears wrong, as

```
df.isnull().values.any()
```

outputs `False`. So, I suspect this is because `samples` is a column of non-numerical values.

How do I plot a seaborn heatmap such that these categorical values are shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just drop the `"samples"` column as well, isn't that what you are looking for?! You can then put the sample names in later using matplotlib's `ax.set_yticklabels` function. Note that you need to reverse sample names list, since matplotlib starts the labeling from the bottom.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("SO_pandassnsheatmap.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = df.drop(["samples", "a", "b", "c", "ratio_a:b", "ratio_c:b"], axis = 1)
ax = sns.heatmap(df2)
ax.set_yticklabels(df.samples.values[::-1])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. However, I would like the y-axis to show the names for "samples", not just indices 0, 1, 2, 3
How does one accomplish that?

Comment: Edited the answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was confused about. Thank you!

Comment: Also, how does one plot the words horizontally as opposed to vertically, i.e. `sample1` is current turned 90 degrees on the y axis

Comment: Use the `rotation` argument: `ax.set_yticklabels(df.samples.values[::-1], rotation=0)`.

Comment: Thank you for this! I think this was the most helpful tidbit for future SO readers: "Note that you need to reverse sample names list, since matplotlib starts the labeling from the bottom."