# seaborn heatmap ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I got an error ' ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''. 
My dataframe doesn't contain any NaNs, and the dtypes look fine, and I even set index as one of the cols.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'volume':[1.2, 0.3, 1.0, 1.8], 'team': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'd' : ['d1', 'd2','d3', 'd4']})
df.set_index("d", inplace=True)
df.isnull().values.any()
df['volume'] = df['volume'].astype(float)
print (df.dtypes)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt="g", cmap='viridis')
plt.show()

team       object
volume    float64
dtype: object
```

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42397469/typeerror-when-plotting-heatmap-with-seaborn) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44254239/seaborn-heatmap-throwing-unexpected-error), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43523115/typeerror-ufunc-isnan-not-supported-for-the-input-types-seaborn-heatmap).

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like this ?

[image]

```
team = np.array([['A'], ['B'],['C'], ['D']])
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'volume':[1.2, 0.3, 1.0, 1.8], 'd' : ['d1', 'd2','d3', 'd4']})
df.set_index("d", inplace=True)
df.isnull().values.any()
df['volume'] = df['volume'].astype(np.float64)
print (df.dtypes)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=team, fmt="", cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your example works, but if i try to make square heatmap and set 'team' for y_axis, and 'd' for x_axis, i got df['volume'] = df['volume'].astype(np.float64). 
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

Comment: I try to make something similar to example in the seaborn heatmap docs, aka: ax = sns.heatmap(flights, annot=True, fmt="d"), but I didn't get how their df different from mine